# java: '.class' expected Error in returning an array

Tags: java, class, input

In my code I get the error "java: '.class' expected" on this line:

```
return a[] ;
```

In this function trying to return integers into an array:

```
 public int[] inputArr() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String lines = br.readLine();        
    String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
    int a[];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {                    
               a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);}
    return a[];
     }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `return a;`, no brackets.

Comment: Also, it's more conventional and less confusing to declare it as `int[] a;`.

Comment: Why is a variable containing one line called "lines"?

Comment: `int[] a = new int[strs.length];` and `return a;`. You really shouldn't instantiate any objects with `System.in` within a function/method. The function/method should have an `InputStream` or `BufferedReader` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the length of your `int` array with the length of your `string` array

```
int [] a = new int [strs.length];
```

After the loop, this can be returned as

```
return a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the array `int a[]=new int[value]` and the value should be an `int` literal or variable. And, u should return only `a` this way: `return a;`